# Dynamically change intent URI in SharedPreferences?

Tags: android

My users can jump to Google Play to rate my app from the Settings screen, by clicking a preference that starts an intent:

In the XML:

```
<Preference
    android:title="@string/prefRate"
    android:summary="@string/prefRateHint">
    <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:data="market://details?id=app.package.name" />
</Preference>
```

In the code:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }
}
```

Now I'm planning to upload to Amazon where the store URL is different. Is there a way to programmatically change the intent URL inside the SharedPreferences before showing the Settings screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's going to add a few bytes to your code, but what about having two seperate prefs_play, prefs_amazon files, and establishing the reference when you find out which store they are working with? That would be the quick-and-dirty way that would come out of my original test of the services, anyway.

Comment: Should have thought of that, need more coffee. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Example:
in preference file is link and you want to change it to another and change also the visible text (Title)

```
<Preference
    android:key="my_key"
    android:title="@string/originalTitle">
    <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:data="https://originallink" />
</Preference>

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://newlink"));
getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("my_key").setIntent(intent);
getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("my_key").setTitle(getString(R.string.newTitle));
```